# getting json data into an array angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angular

I am not sure what i am missing from my code but currently i am not presented with any errors when i run it but i am also not seeing the results that i am expecting. I have a json file that i am loading into an array and would like to loop through that array and display parts of its data onto the page.

Here is what i have so far:

**Service file**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class AddressDataService{
    addressData: Array<any>;

    constructor(private http:Http){ }
    getAddressData(){
        return this.http.get('./api/addressData.json')
                 .map((res:Response) => res.json());
    }
}
```

**JSON File**

```
[{
    "type": "home",
    "id": 1
}, {
    "type": "apartment",
    "id": 2
}, {
    "type": "homeless",
    "id": 3
}]
```

**Component File**

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { AddressDataService } from './address.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: '....',
  styleUrls: ['./styles.css'],
  providers: [AddressDataService]
})

constructor(private addressDataService: AddressDataService) {}
  addressData = [];
  getAddressData() {
  this.addressDataService.getAddressData()
                   .subscribe(data => this.addressData = data);
}
```

**HTML File**

```
<div *ngFor="let addressDetail of addressData">
    {{addressDetail.type}}
</div>
```

Am i doing this the right way?

Comment: When do you call `getAddressData` for the component?

Comment: @ExplosionPills now that you brought it to my attention i actually don't see that i do call `getAddressData` in my component - would i do that in oninit function that i will have to create?

Comment: I think `ngOnInit` would be a great spot to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call your `getAddressData` for example in your `OnInit`, I assume you want to fetch the data when navigated to page.

So:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getAddressData();
}
```

When this is handled, you will face another issue. Http-requests don't allow relative paths, so

```
return this.http.get('./api/addressData.json')
```

will cause an error, you need to replace the dot in your "url" with the actual complete path for the json file, starting from the top level folder.

Comment: Thanks - but i wanted to ask about the actual complete path: i have tried the following but i get a 404 for the file: 
`'./src/api/addressData.json'` and the full path is `/Users/userName/Projects/Angular2/quickstart/src/api/addressData`

Comment: Then you should use it like: `return this.http.get('src/api/addressData.json')` So you were almost correct, just remove the dot :)

Comment: Thanks! - i also used `http://myjson.com/` and worked nicely for storing my json.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

In your component file:

```
.subscribe(
      data => {
        const helperArray = [];
        for (let key in data) {
          helperArray.push(data[key]);
        }
      }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something in your component class needs to call your getAddressData method. Either the constructor, or a better option is to implement OnInit and call it from there.